# Symfony Local Webserver doesn't display error

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using my local symfony web server with **bin/console server:start**, and also tried to use php -S into my public directory.

The problem is that when I get an Error 500 before symfony used to show me that beautifull interface with all the error and since one week I just get

```
"Oops! An Error Occurred
The server returned a "500 Internal Server Error".
Something is broken. Please let us know what you were doing when this error occurred. We will fix it as soon as possible. Sorry for any inconvenience caused"
```

And nothings else... My **bin/console about** say me that I am in development environment. Also my profiler is enable and works. So I don't think it's an environment problem. I'm able to get the error by watching into the **bin/console server:log** or by using the sentry/sentry-symfony package but I would like to get back my error interface.

I tried to look in google but I wasn't able to find a clue, just some ways to avoid the problem by using another way...

Do you have some hints which could help me, or a file that I could need to share ?

Thanks

I'm running a Symfony 4.4.5 Project in Windows.

Comment: the first place to look is your actual PHP `error_log`

Comment: In which env did you run `symfony`?

Comment: From my webprofiler into my phpinfo() error_log has no value. I'm running my project in my local environment on windows 10 accross the ubuntu shell

Comment: A 500 error implies that Symfony itself it never being reached.  Maybe a permission issue or maybe some sort of Windows firewall problem.  Create a new project and see if it will run out of the box.

Comment: @AlexandreCorvino I wanted to know the env you run between `dev` and `prod`. Because in `prod` error are displayed as generic : [Since these pages contain a lot of sensitive internal information, Symfony won't display them in the production environment. Instead, it'll show a simple and generic error page](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution, I took a older version of my project and I installed one by one all the new dependencies that I had.

I saw that installing error-handler was the thing which broke error page.
However, if you remove it, after installing it, it won't work the files into the vendor are not the same if you never installed it and you installed and remove it. 
So remove the error-handler with composer, remove the vendor and launch a composer install!